# Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes. - For INT datatype?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am aware innodb imposes a limit on key size, but an INT?

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `db`.`TAGS` (

 `tag_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `tag_text` VARCHAR( 700 ) NULL ,
 `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 `xxx_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'This is for ease of reference lookup later',
 `user_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `TAG_FACT_RELATION_relation_id` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `tag_id` ) ,
UNIQUE INDEX  `tag_UNIQUE` (  `tag_text` ASC ) ,
UNIQUE INDEX  `tag_id_UNIQUE` (  `tag_id` ASC ) ,
INDEX  `fk_TAGS_TAG_FACT_RELATION1_idx` (  `TAG_FACT_RELATION_relation_id` ASC ) ,
CONSTRAINT  `fk_TAGS_TAG_FACT_RELATION1` FOREIGN KEY (  `TAG_FACT_RELATION_relation_id` ) REFERENCES  `meepl`.`TAG_FACT_RELATION` (
`relation_id`
) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

There error says:

```
#1709 - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

Any ideas? I have been muching around with data types for ages.

Comment: What about `tag_text`

Comment: In addition to @juergend following excerpt of the manual to CREATE INDEX: *Note
Prefix limits are measured in bytes, whereas the prefix length in CREATE INDEX statements is interpreted as number of characters for nonbinary data types (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT). Take this into account when specifying a prefix length for a column that uses a multi-byte character set.*

Comment: Thanks, yes it looks like tag_text. How do I fix this without making me VARCHAR(100) ? Should I just remove it as an index?

Comment: You could set a prefix length, i.e. `UNIQUE INDEX tag_UNIQUE ( tag_text (150) ), ...` The first 150 characters of the column have to be unique, this could take up to 600 Bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error: The maximum column size is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761867/mysql-error-the-maximum-column-size-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but I had a similar issue.

Your `tag_text` column has a UNIQUE_INDEX and that is what is causing the issue, not the INT datatype.

Change your MySql installation to enable larger index columns by enabling the innodb_large_prefix setting.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: You may also have to change the row format for the specific tables to DYNAMIC.

Comment: Thanks this was a big help.
Too many Unque_index constraints threw this error for me.