# MySQL error: The maximum column size is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, database, size, innodb, mysql-workbench

When I run a program which does something with MySQL, I got this error message:

> 2015-06-10 15:41:12,250 ERROR app.wsutils 419 INCRON: Error: ('HY000',
> '[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.7-rc-log]Index column
> size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes. (1709)
> (SQLExecDirectW)')

I Googled a little bit and found this error might be related to the `innodb_large_prefix` option. However, I am using MySQL 5.7.7 RC, which has already set `innodb_large_prefix` to be "ON" (checked in MySQL Workbench), allowing up to 3072 bytes. I am not sure if that is the problem with `innodb_large_prefix` or not.

Anyway, does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: What does your program do?

Comment: I have no idea... do some creations of tables or calculations? I am just a front end user...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 60):

From Wamp Version 3.2.6
Just edit this file:
**C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\my.ini**
Change the config for `innodb-default-row-format` value
from `innodb-default-row-format=compact`
to  `innodb-default-row-format=dynamic`
Restart mysql

Comment: This is the simplest answer, although the question was asked over 6 years ago.

Comment: Awesome, worked just great. Wamp Server on Windows using MySQL 5.7.x on command line restoring a big dump

Comment: Thanks, worked smooth for me using wamp with mysql 8.0

Comment: This is such a timesaver. I had no idea the creators built this in.. but of course they did! ;)

Answer (score 37):

With the help of the answer given by BK435, I did the following and solved the problem.

```
set global innodb_file_format = BARRACUDA;
set global innodb_large_prefix = ON;
create table test (........) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: As of MariaDB 10.2.2, of course :) You can also set `SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC';`

Comment: Thnx Adam! innodb_default_row_format = DYNAMIC worked for me! +1

Comment: This approach also worked for me.  I was exporting from Enterprise MySQL and attempting to import into MariaDB 10.0.x.   ... on a side note, the import worked perfectly fine on MariaDB 10.3.x (for whatever reason).

Comment: Makes sure your MySQL version is greater than 5.5 or none of these settings will have an effect.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. It also worked for me in 10.3.17-MariaDB

Answer (score 22):

Your column that you are trying to index is too large and your settings must not be correct for `innodb_large_prefix`. There are a couple [prerequisites](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/07/29/using-innodb-large-prefix-to-avoid-error-1071/) parameters that also have to be set in order for `innodb_large_prefix` to work correctly.

You can check to make sure that [innodb_large_prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html) is set by running:

`show global variables like 'innodb_lar%';`

Here are a couple prerequisites for using innodb_large_prefix:

You need to set your global variable innodb_file_format=[BARRACUDA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_barracuda)

to check settings run: `show global variables like 'innodb_fil%';`

At the table level you have to use ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

for [Innodb](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format-specification.html), rows are stored in COMPACT format (ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT) by default.

Comment: How do you do that "At the database level"?  Perhaps you mean `SET GLOBAL`?

Comment: You better configure these settings in my.cnf or else they are stored in memory and hence lost when restarting MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: @RickJames - Yes doing this at a database level is enough. Infact, doing it at the particular table level also will solve the problem.

Comment: In some cases where I was trying to `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET`, I was using MySQL 5.5 where the default `ROW_FORMAT` for InnoDB was `COMPACT`. Using `ALTER TABLE foo ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC, CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset` did the trick.

Comment: If you, like me, need to change your mysqldump file to add `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` to each create table statement, try the following:
```sed -i 's/ENGINE=InnoDB/ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC/g' database_dump.sql```

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherSchultz, I wasn't aware MySQL 5.5 was configured like this and your suggestion did the trick!

Comment: Hey @disperse, thanks a lot. This did the trick for me. Saved me many hours of work trying to upgrade mysql too, which is what others 'ordered' me to do.

Answer (score 17):

I was using MariaDB version 10.1.38 and used all of the below given commands but it did not work -

```
set global innodb_large_prefix = ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

set global innodb_file_per_table = ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

set global innodb_file_format = Barracuda;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC';
```

Because after you restart your MySQL (or MariaDB), these settings will not reflect back using the command at the mysql prompt: show variables like 'innodb%';

**Then I edited My.ini and added these settings in the file at below location-
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini**

```
## Innodb settings to bypass error of max size 737
innodb-file-format=barracuda
innodb-file-per-table=ON
innodb-large-prefix=ON
## Above 3 didnot work so i added below
innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC'
```

source:https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28675824/Why-am-I-unable-to-turn-innodb-large-prefix-ON-successfully-Every-time-I-reboot-mySql-on-my-Ubuntu-VPS-it-resets-to-OFF.html

Comment: The addition of `innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC'` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

For me using Mariadb 10.1.31, just add this while you login in Mysql CLI:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = Barracuda;

SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = ON;

SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = ON;

SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC';
```

Comment: SET GLOBAL innodb_default_row_format = 'DYNAMIC'; might be enough

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the `innodb-default-row-format` variable to **dynamic**.

- If you are using phpMyAdmin, navigate to [variables](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/server/variables) and search for `row format`.
- If you are using WampServer, navigate to `my.ini` file like:
  `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\my.ini`

For more info, visit [MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_default_row_format)

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following options to my.cnf

```
    [mysqld]
    innodb_file_format=Barracuda
    innodb_file_per_table=1
    innodb_large_prefix=1
```

Then, restart mysql server the problem will be resolved.

Comment: You forgot to provide value to `innodb_large_prefix`

Comment: I confirm this solution works for MariaDB 10.1.44, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Go to mysql config in this file **my.cnf**

change this line

`innodb-default-row-format=compact`

to

`innodb-default-row-format=dynamic`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

From Wamp Version 3.2.6
Just edit this file: *C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\my.ini*
Change the config for `innodb-default-row-format` value
from `innodb-default-row-format=compact`
to `innodb-default-row-format=dynamic`
Restart mysql

Comment: No need to repost what was already answered in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error despite having `innodb_large_prefix` configured correctly.

The issue was in used collation. My db had default collation set to `utf8mb4_bin` (you can check it in phpmyadmin "Operations" tab for database). It means it uses 4 bytes per char, while utf8 collation (e.g. utf8_unicode_ci) uses 3 bytes per char.

in this case you can either use different collation e.g. by adding `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement, or limit the index size by using just a part of the column value 
like `KEY 'identifier' (column1(5),column2(10))`.

See also related question: [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (MySQL version 5.6) the issue was that I was trying to create a table with a column that can have up to 256 characters (the db uses utf8 collation), so 3 bytes per 1 utf8 character = 256*3=768 bytes. The fix was to simply have 255 characters instead of 256.

I could also set innodb_large_prefix, like others suggest, but in my case it was easier to just have fewer symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @sasank-mukkamala said , for me only adding `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` to create command did it rightly.

```
create table `NameOfTheTable` (........) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using Mysql 5.7

Click PHPMyAdmin (home)
Click Variables
On innodb default row formart, click edit then enter 2, then click save
It will show variable value as dynamic
Import table again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I tried to create a String primary key with varchar(254). Easy to overlook sometimes.. So double check your index type and length as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is working with MySQL 5.6 the only solution that I found was to update to MySQL 5.7 and setting `my.cnf` as mentioned in previous comments (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465002/2300390).

Answer (score -3):

I had the same error but on a different issue. I got this error while importing a data (data and schema) script. Deleting the Unique Index fixed the issue for me.

Answer taken from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853828/index-column-size-too-large-the-maximum-column-size-is-767-bytes-for-int-dat)

Answer (score -6):

Set the below system variables:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size.................................... 702545920
innodb_file_format......................................... Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check................................... ON
innodb_file_format_max..................................... Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table...................................... ON
innodb_large_prefix........................................ ON
innodb_log_file_size....................................... 50331648
```

Also, make sure when you create your schema you create it as **Latin1**.  That is what finally fixed me.

Comment: Creating your schema in latin1 is probably not a good idea for most sites that require internationalization.  The reason that worked for you is because latin1 requires fewer bytes to store teh the same length varchar.  However, latin1 won't be compatible with sites that need to store utf8 or utf8mb4 characters.