# Where to add innodb_large_prefix

Tags: mysql

I am running into a bit of an issue.

You see I have made a WordPress website locally using WAMP and everything seemed to be working fine, until I tried to get the MySQL database imported onto the new live site where it gave an error:

**"#1709 - Index column size is to large, The maximum column size is 767 bytes"**

See image of the complete error here:
[image: See image of the complete error here]

Now I have found some answers to what may be causing this here:

[MySQL error: The maximum column size is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761867/mysql-error-the-maximum-column-size-is-767-bytes/50945855#50945855)

And here:

[mysql change innodb_large_prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847015/mysql-change-innodb-large-prefix)

And although I understand what needs to be imlemented code wise, I am none the wiser as to where the code actually needs to be placed.

As aside from importing and exporting and editing the database credentials I never had to do anything else with MySQL, it is all a bit foreign to me.
And though I am more than happy to look more deeply into it at a later point in time, at this point I rather just want my live site to be working.

Comment: If you know what to do: can you share these thoughts such that we can help you implement them?

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out, apparently I had to edit the SQL file itself and had to add `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` at the end of every CREATE TABLE Query which uses the INNODB engine.

So I changed this:

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
  `visit_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `visitor_cookie` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `subscriber_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `url` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `ip` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Into

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
  `visit_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `visitor_cookie` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `subscriber_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `url` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `ip` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`)
) ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Then I re-imported the file onto the local server and then did a new export to the live server... and it is live now...finally.

I still find it a bit strange that mySQL doesn't automatically set rows to dynamic, once you exceed a certain amount of characters ( 747) and that it still works inside the existing database eventhough it shouldn't work...but maybe WAMP just has different environment settings vs the live server.

Anyway thanks all!